# How does go mod generate the version and timestamp from a commit id

Tags: go

when I specify a git commit id in go.mod like "xxx.xxx.org/xxxx/common 686937ffa3bf". Then it seems that go mod will generate a version and a timestamp automatically like below "xxx.xxx.org/xxxx/common v0.0.137-0.20191229121626-686937ffa3bf". What I was wondering is where are "v0.0.137" and "0.20191229121626" from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [doc](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) go mod use a [pseudo-version](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions) when you specify an untagged commit

**v0.0.137** is the recent tagged version in the commit's graph before the specified commit

and **0.20191229121626** is the commit time in UTC